# why usepackage{fancyhdr} does not apply when I use \chapter*{title}?

Tags: fancyhdr, fancytabs

I have a problem with the `fancyhdr` package: I use the book documentclass and I have a chapter which is defined like this: 
`\chapter*{Introduction} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Introduction}`

The problem be, that what I defined for my header is by section:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}  
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyheadoffset[R]{0pt}
```

But it appears in the header in special chapter when I put: `\chapter*****{Chapter-title}`  is the title of the last section of the last chapter (in chapter conclusion) and the title of last chapter (in the introduction).
How come? What did I miss?

[image]

Here for example I wish to put the title of the chapter introduction as I am in this chapter but it shows me the title of the last chapter.

Comment: Oops, that should have been \let\slshape=\relax .

Comment: I have found solution is that after   \chapter*{Introduction} I set  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{Introduction}}{\MakeUppercase{Introduction}}